# How to avoid returning certain properties and Foreign Entities when calling GetProperties on an Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am making the call:

```
var properties = person.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                        BindingFlags.Public |
                                                        BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This returns what I want except for, it also returns a property I don't want called Updated, but I can easily just ignore this.  It also returns `CarReference` and `Car` which I don't want to include.  How can I exclude these fields?  Currently, I have a list of excluded properties and if the name matches one of those, I just skip over it, but I want it to be more generic instead of hard-coding `"CarReference"` and `"Car"` for example

Comment: Well how can it be "more generic" - what criterion can be used to determine which properties (not fields - it's important to differentiate between the two) you want to return and which you don't?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I wasn't sure if there was some flag I can pass to avoid returning those or if they had a certain base type I can use to avoid getting them.  Something on the PropertyInfo object that I can use without hard-coding?  I just called it fields, I will update the post to say Properties.

Comment: Avoid returning *which*? You haven't given us any description about which properties shouldn't be returned except that you don't want to include `CarReference` or `Car`... what's special about those properties? Should `Bus` and `BusReference` properties be returned? You really need to give more context here.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I initially was trying to do `person.GetType().GetFields()`, but this returned nothing.

Comment: I'd hope not, as without specifying binding flags you'll only get public fields - and you generally shouldn't *have* public fields. Properties are almost certainly the right thing here.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I stated in my post: `It also returns CarReference and Car which I don't want to include`  I think this says that I don't want to return or include CarReference or Car.  They are foreign entities to Person entity I am trying to get properties from.

Comment: Yes, you've given the specific names of types you don't want to return. But that's the verbal equivalent of the hard-coding you're trying to avoid. If it's *actually* a matter of "I don't want to return any foreign entities" then that's a different matter, and that's what I've been trying to tease out of you.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Well, if you put it that way, I guess you are right, so I guess what I am asking is how can I avoid bringing in the Foreign Entities?  I am not sure how I would handle the other situation, where I want to avoid certain properties?  I guess I could filter them out, but that does not make it very generic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but here is a snippet which could help you. There are criterions for some properties of automatically generated Entity Framework "Entity" classes:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
var destinationProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties(flags);

foreach (var property in destinationProperties)
{
    var type = property.PropertyType;

    // Ignore reference property (e.g. TripReference)
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityReference<>))
    {
        // ...
    }

    // Ignore navigation property (e.g. Trips)
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
    {
        // ...
    }

    // Ignore ID (edmscalar) property (e.g. TripID)
    if (property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EdmScalarPropertyAttribute), false).Any())
    {
        // ..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Namespace" property listed in the PropertyType, Foreign Entities would be skipped by the following statement:     if (type.Namespace != "System")

```
        using (var db = new Entities.YourEntities())
        {
            var originalObj = db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (var prop in originalObj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var type = prop.PropertyType;

                if (type.Namespace != "System")
                    continue;

                var name = prop.Name;
                var value = prop.GetValue(originalObj, null);

                //your code here
            }
        }
```